# How to set deployXML to false in Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I want to secure a Apache Tomcat server. How to do that ?

**Note :** I read somewhere that if `deployXML = false` is set, then it will secure the server. In addition to that, I have read the documentation from this link [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html) and the documentation told to modify the `<Host>` attribute but I can't find it. But I don't know in which `.xml` file I have to do.

So, where should I place the conf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailing list archive reply mentioned [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201408.mbox/%3CCAAqVxAy=H05sCwPmGvQhx4T53A1RcQbbgf5ZB+0TEfk1WCm+2Q@mail.gmail.com%3E) is given below :

> Just move all the necessary configuration that was
>   in `/META-INF/context.xml` into "`conf/Catalina/localhost/<app>.xml`"
>   (i.e. `conf/<service>/<host>/<app>.xml`).